# How can I add Facebook authentication and friend location without showing the user a browser?

Tags: networking, facebook

I'm working on a multiplatform game (PC/iOS/Android) and was looking into using Facebook as a login method and friend finder. I know Battle.net does this without having to bring up a browser window and ask a user for permissions, and they ask for your email and password when doing so.

Is there a known API for doing this, or did Blizzard work out something with Facebook to do this, or are they using some back end service to add those permissions behind the scenes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this post](http://socialtimes.com/blizzard-integrates-facebook-into-battle-net-starts-with-starcraft-ii_b12146), Blizzard had worked out a special deal with Facebook to allow that functionality. Couple that with [this post from Facebook](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=22565) which states

> There is no way to do this for security reasons.  Either you can wait for Facebook Connect for Mobile/Iphone, or you can use browser based authentication as it currently exists.

it looks like you're out of luck.